# BigQuery: Reached maximum number of iterations of view resolution or security filter application

Tags: sql-server, google-bigquery, legacy

I recently started converting some of my BigQuery views to Standard SQL from Legacy SQL.

Up to this point it's been going well. All the views run perfectly, even the views that join onto other views.

The problem I am experiencing is when I attempt to connect to one of my views through a visualization program I get the following error:
"***Reached maximum number of iterations of view resolution or security filter application***"

When my views were coded in Legacy SQL I never got this error. So basically, the only thing that has changed is the conversion to Standard SQL, and now the error.

I find it particularly weird, as the views all run without error and produce the flattened tables. The error only occurs when i attempt to convert the view to a table via Google scripts, or when i attempt to connect to the view via the visualization program.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Franscois

Comment: Can you provide a job ID for a sample failed query? That may help someone from the BigQuery team to debug the issue.

Comment: Sure! Job ID: vital-platform-791:bquijob_4a445128_15842df8871

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on a similar issue. This is in the running for the least informative error messages ever. Google Support informed us that this error results when you exceed 8 nested views.

However, that in standard SQL, that number is no longer based on the maximum depth of views, but rather the sum of views traversals. For example, if you have a view that references a view, that references a table, that's 2. If in that view, you reference two views that reference tables, that's 4, and if you have 5 of them, that's 10 and you're query is killed.

You haven't included your query for the view in your question, but does it reference other views?

If so, I'd suggest putting the queries from those views directly in your view and trying again. Or just cutting out some of them other views.

Yes, this is a totally hacky solution, but it's the best that support has offered us thus far.

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery supports up to eight levels of nested views

See more details about [Views](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/querying-data#views)